# How to get the elements of an array using pass by reference?

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to get the data from an array. The array gets filled up the receive function of a protocol. How do I get the data of array from `get_msg_data` from `main`

```
typdef struct {
    msg_hdr hdr;
    uint8_t msg_data[64];
} msg;

msg msg_t;

static uint8_t *data;

void get_msg_data(const uint8_t *data) {
    data = &msg_t.msg_data;
}

int main() {
//Calling function 
    get_msg_data(&data);
}
```

I am seeing all 0's with this approach. What is the correct way?
I tried setting all the data of `msg_data`n to 0xff and tried to retrieve the same data in `main` function.

Comment: Typically, you must memcpy.

Comment: `msg` is only defined as a type in `get_msg_data` please edit your post and include a [mre] that shows your actual problem.

Comment: If you are not getting compiler warnings when you compile this, turn up your compiler warnings, e.g., `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. The `get_msg_data` function takes a pointer to `uint8_t`, yet code passes a pointer to a pointer to `uint8_t`. Inside `get_msg_data` `data` is a pointer (a copy of the pointer which was passed) so the assignment `data = ...` has no effect outside of the function. You need to review pointers in your learning materials.

Comment: Please think of the `&` operator as a *pointer-to* operator. When you do `&data` you get a *pointer to* the variable `data`. Which in your case would have the type `uint8_t **`.

Comment: it is not clear what exactly do you want to achieve. You have uint8_t *data and want to address msg_data[] array?

Comment: Let's say that you rewrote the function like this: `void get_msg_data(const uint8_t **data) { *data = msg_t.msg_data; }` - Now comes the next problem: Your `static uint8_t *data;` is a pointer to a non-`const` `uint8_t`  so you can't do `get_msg_data(&data);`. Make it `static const uint8_t *data;` and it'd work.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Thanks for pointing that out . I am unsure what is the correct approach to get the 'msg_t.msg_data'.

Comment: Either make the `static` variable a pointer to a `const uint8_t` or change the function to take a `uint8_t **data` as a parameter.

Comment: Do you mean this ?`static uint8_t data;

void get_msg_data(const uint8_t **data) {
    data = &msg_t.msg_data;
}



int main() {
//Calling function 
    get_msg_data(&data);
}`

Comment: No, I meant it exactly as I wrote it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *copy* the contents of `msg_t.msg_data` into a separate buffer named `data`, you'd do something like:

```
void get_msg_data( uint8_t *data ) // not const
{
   memcpy( data, msg_t.msg_data, sizeof msg_t.msg_data );
}

int main( void )
{
  uint8_t data[64];

  get_msg_data( data );
  ...
}
```

If you just want `data` to *point to* `msg_t.msg_data`, *and* you want it to be read-only, you'd do

```
void get_msg_data( const uint8_t **data )
{
  *data = msg_t.msg_data;
}

int main( void )
{
  const uint8_t *data;

  get_msg_data( &data );
  ...
}
```

Unless it's the operand of the `sizeof`, `_Alignof`, or `sizeof` operators, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will decay to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

At least these issues:

**Save time: Enable all warnings**

`get_msg_data(&data);` passes the address of a pointer where a pointer is expected.

**Post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**

**Post how output was determine**

"I am seeing all 0's with this approach." --> Code has no output.